# Loading page in Django based on its ID

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I've been working with Django in order to make my portfolio and I've managed to make a simple page manager. The problem is, it does not work how I want it to work:

1. I create the page.
2. It loads the content I gave it.
3. With jQuery, I load only that content (as formatted HTML).
4. It shows itself without reloading or moving to another page.

The problem is with the last two steps, I can't get the view and template to only load one.

Views.py:

```
def paginas(request, title):
    get_page = Page.objects.all() # I can't think of a way to make a proper filter
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'get_page': get_page}, context_instance=RequestContext(request), mimetype="text/html")
```

Template.html:

```
{% if get_page %}
    {% for page in get_page %}
            {{ page.content|safe }}
            <p>Full path is {{ request.get_full_path }} and page id is {{ page.id }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>Nothing.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I know I should filter it, but I don't know how.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tbh, the django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#design-your-urls) explains urls, parameters and forms very clear, but here's the idea:

```
url(r'^/someapp/(?P<page_id>\d+)/$', paginas),


def paginas(request, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs.pop('page_id')
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, id=id)
    # etcetera


class Page(models.Model):
    # regular stuff
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/someapp/%d/" % self.id
```

Comment: I think it also passes url args kwargs to the request function, so this would be also valid `def paginas(request, page_id=None): ...`.

Comment: On other hand your example is incorrect. request.GET stores data from url after `?` mark, so it would be correct in case of `<some domain>/someapp/?page_id=<page_id>`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: isn't it even more explicit just to accept the `page_id` as the second param? what benefit does accessing it through `**kwargs` provide??

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I was able to find a way out of this. It was a problem based on the URL construction.

Comment: @dm03514 well import this says explicit is better then implicit, however I like the dynamics kwargs offers, ofcourse this example doesn't require any :-)

Answer (score 1):

In `paginas` you are obviously getting all Pages.

To get one page you can use the `get` function

```
def paginas(request, title):
   try:
     your_page = Page.objects.get(title=title)
   except Page.DoesNotExist:
     # error no page for that title
     # could use built in get_object_or_404 as ArgsKwargs suggested
```

It's also important to consider using a slug to make sure encoding is correct.  The page id would be even better to use

Comment: I've got my answer already, but I never thought of exceptions. It will be useful to raise 404 errors. Thank you.

Comment: get_object_or_404 is a django function I didn't make that up :-)

Comment: yes `get_object_or_404` is right way I just like to show the `get` function